Double sum to "double sum" doubt: what is $\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)$

QUESTION: If $$\sum_{r=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n\choose r}=a,$$ then find the value of $$\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)$$ in terms of $n$ and $a$

I did it as follows:
\begin{align*}
S&=\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)\\
&=\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{n-i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{n-j}{n \choose j}\right)\\
&=n\cdot\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{1}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{1}{n \choose j}\right)-\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)\\
\Rightarrow 2S&=n\cdot\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{1}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{1}{n \choose j}\right)\\
&=n\left[\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n-i}{n \choose i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right]\tag{*}\\
&=n\left[n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{1}{n \choose i}-\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right]\\
&=n\left[n \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{n \choose i}}_{\text{add $n$}}-{\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{i}{n \choose i}}_{\text{subtract $n$}}}+\sum_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right]\\
&=n^2{\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n \choose i}}\\
&=n^2a\\
\Rightarrow S&=\dfrac{an^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
I did this and the answer is correct as I checked it, but I later had a feeling that the step $(*)$ isn't totally correct. I think some part of the sum is missing...Am I correct? Please let me know if the step$(*)$ is correct or not.
And if my solution is wrong(which possibly is), then please show what the correct solution development is.
Thanks in advance!

I think it is wrong that $$\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{n-i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{n-j}{n \choose j}\right)\
=n\cdot\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)-\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)$$

@mathlove Oops! Typing mistake. I have edited it now

Your approach is sound and the result is correct. Here is a verification in form of a slightly different two-step approach. In the first step we reduce the double sum to a single sum. In the second step we use the symmetry of the binomial coefficient and calculate the result.
We show the following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\left(\frac{i}{\binom{n}{i}}+\frac{j}{\binom{n}{j}}\right)
=\frac{n^2}{2}\sum_{r=0}^n\frac{1}{\binom{n}{r}}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
As first step we reduce the double sum of the left-hand sum to a single sum. We do this in a slightly more general setting. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}}\color{blue}{\left(a_i+a_j\right)}
&=\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}a_i+\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}a_j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^na_i+\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}a_j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i\sum_{j=i+1}^n1+\sum_{j=1}^na_j\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}1\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(n-i)a_i+\sum_{j=1}^nja_j\\
&=na_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}((n-i)+i)a_i+na_n\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=n\sum_{i=0}^na_i}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
In the second step we take the special setting from (1). We get from (2)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\left(\frac{i}{\binom{n}{i}}+\frac{j}{\binom{n}{j}}\right)
&=n\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i}{\binom{n}{i}}\\
&=n\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n-i}{\binom{n}{i}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
where we change the order of summation in the last line $i\to n-i$ and use the symmetry $\binom{n}{i}=\binom{n}{n-i}$. We get from (3)
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{2\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n}\left(\frac{i}{\binom{n}{i}}+\frac{j}{\binom{n}{j}}\right)}}
=n\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{i+(n-i)}{\binom{n}{i}}
\color{blue}{=n^2\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{1}{\binom{n}{i}}}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.

Since the two summands inside the parentheses depend on $i$ and $j$ separately,
you can somewhat split
$$\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)$$
taking care of the indices. You can see the dependence $i<j$, and also you can deduce that $0\leq i <n-1$ and $i+1\leq j < n$ (if $j$ depends on $i$) or $1\leq j < n$ and $0<i\leq j-1$ (if $i$ depends on $j$).
So, you can "split" either this way
$$\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\sum_{j=i+1}^n\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right),$$
(making $i$ independent, ang $j$ depending on $i$) or
$$\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{j}{n \choose j}+\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\dfrac{i}{n \choose i}\right)$$
(making $j$ independent, and $i$ depending on $j$).

So, is my step (*) correct or not? Our results seem to diverge. I have broken the double sum into two sums, whereas you have split it into a sum within a sum...

I think it shouldn't be correct, because if you split in two sums, then you are also considering summands where $i\geq j$. For example, the summand with $i=2$ and $j=1$ shouldn't appear in the final result, but it is possible with your separate sums.

If that is the case, can you please tell me (and explain why/how) what's the actual answer in terms of $a$ and $n$?

In your first split the left summand to the right within the parentheses is $\sum_{j=i+1}^n i/\binom{n}{i}=i/\binom{n}{i}\sum_{j=i+1}^n 1 = (n-i)\cdot i/\binom{n}{i}$.


I later had a feeling that the step (∗)
isn't totally correct.

I think the step (∗) is correct.
$$\underset{0\leq i <j \leq n}{\sum\sum}\left(\dfrac{1}{n \choose i}+\dfrac{1}{n \choose j}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n-i}{n \choose i}+\sum_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{j}{n \choose j}\tag1$$

I think some part of the sum is missing

I think you did nothing wrong.
To see this, let us consider an easy case $n=3$.
We have
$$\begin{align}(i,j)=(0,1),(0,2),(0,3)&
\\(1,2),(1,3)&
\\(2,3)&\end{align}$$

The number of $i=0$ is $3\ (=n-i)$.

The number of $i=1$ is $2\ (=n-i)$.

The number of $i=2$ is $1\ (=n-i)$.

The number of $j=1$ is $1\ (=j)$.

The number of $j=2$ is $2\ (=j)$.

The number of $j=3$ is $3\ (=j)$.


So, for $n=3$, $(1)$ holds.
I think, from this, you can see why $(1)$ holds.
